# How to iterate a sequence of bits or access a specific bit in NASM Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bit

```
SECTION .data
  source: db 01101001b , 11011100b

SECTION .text
  global main
  main:

  mov EAX,source   ; Address to my source of bits
```

How can I iterate each bit in the `source` variable (16 bits there)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate the bits of a value use shifts and masking, just as you would in C.

For getting the value of a single bit you could use the `bt` instruction, which sets CF to the value of a selected bit in a register or memory location.